# how to prevent find_by from adding nil to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using find_by (normally use where) like the following:

```
 out=[]
 Rails.logger.info("here is: #{b}")
 b.each { |v| out << Frag.find_by(frag_key: v) unless nil } if b.count>0
```

I'd like to not add nil on a miss to the out array. How could I do this? The above doesn't work - ideally I'd like to keep it to a single line. I tried reject(nil) but that also wasn't working. How would I tell rails to not add nil to the out array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out = b.map{|v| Frag.find_by(frag_key: v)}.compact
```

Your `if b.count > 0` is redundant; if `b` is empty, then `each`/`map` iteration will be trivial.

Comment: This is pretty inefficient, if the result set is very large; consider checking out @Swards' answer.

Answer (score 4):

`where` will take an array as input and do everything you want with a simple statement.

```
out = Frag.where(frag_key: b)
```

Much improved performance as well.

Comment: why would performance be better - not questioning; just curious. I tend to use where. Would this be adequate record?

Comment: `where` with an array argument will execute a single SQL statement; looping over the array with `find_by` will execute one statement for each pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find_by!` method. This will raise a `RecordNotFound` error if nil is returned.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

> The find_by! method behaves exactly like find_by, except that it will raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if no matching record is found.

Example

```
Client.find_by! first_name: 'does not exist'
=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

`find_by` returns the first record matching a condition or `nil`.